# What is load-time weaving?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am using load-time weaving for a spring (2.5.x) project but I don't know what it is the purpose of it in general. I tried little googling but didn't find the upcoming pages useful. The only thing I understood is that it is something about AOP.

I noticed that it is used for older spring versions also wondering why is that?

Comment: This is not a good question for SO.  This information is readily available on the Internet and should be be researched if you actually want to learn about it (and then more specific questions could be asked as needed). http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html
Quickly though...it is AOP, it's application of AOP.  If you don't understand AOP then you won't understand LTW.

Comment: The more specific question may be comparing load time vs runtime weaving (basic Spring AOP) where runtime revolves around the concept of proxies and load time modifies the class byte code which allows for more complete AOP (wider range of pointcuts...less concern with having to be able to proxy a class).  There is also likely a marginal performance increase with LTW but it also introduces further complexity.

Comment: I am not really agree. ovunccetin 's answer explains with super simplicity, besides that great majority of the answers in SO can be found somehow from the web already. I know about AOP & have been using it, without really knowing the details. May be the title is too wide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask: #1 in particular & #3 would also apply

Comment: You can leave it up to the community.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Weaving is an AOP concept and it is the phase of integrating the aspects with the targeted code. After weaving, aspects are applied to the original code.

This process can take place in different times like compile and load. [This](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html) article explains the different weaving times and LTW of AspectJ.

It says about LTW:

> Load-time weaving (LTW) is simply binary weaving defered until the point that a class loader loads a class file and defines the class to the JVM.

Comment: Eclipselink also needs load time weaving (by default).  There's a way to do compile time weaving but I've never messed with it.